# Table's <TD> right border issue

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

Please take a look at this fiddle

```
jsfiddle.net/Qstuw/2/
```

As you see from picture first row's right border is in different place. I'm trying to set all right borders look like 1 line - I mean at the same place

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Can I just ask: why are you trying to set an `11.5px` font-size? A monitor can't render sub-pixel sizes, so it'll round to either `11px` or `12px`. But either way it won't be the size you specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a transparent left border to all of your `div`-s - http://jsfiddle.net/Qstuw/4/

```
div.Answer {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Then, you could use `div.Answer.SelectedDiv{border-left-color:#90db99}` in order to override only the color instead all `border-left`. And this way if border's width is changed there's no need to change it in two places.

Answer (score 2):

See http://jsfiddle.net/Qstuw/3/

```
div.Answer {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 4px; /* 4px margin-left */
    padding-left: 10px;
}

div.Answer.SelectedDiv{
    border-left: 4px solid #90db99; /* same to border-left */
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left:0; /* reset margin-left */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's that 4px border on the left of the selected answer that's doing it.

```
div.Answer.SelectedDiv{
border-left: 4px solid #90db99;
}
```

You could just add a border to the left of all your answers.

```
div.Answer {
border-left:4px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: this will break if the background isn't white :-P